# Can you cast a whole Fortran array

Tags: arrays, casting, fortran

Is the following code acceptable for all Fortran compilers? It works fine in Intel, but not sure if it's in the standard:

```
real, allocatable :: rArray(:)
double precision, allocatable :: dArray(:)

allocate(rArray(10))
rArray = 1.0

allocate(dArray, SOURCE=dble(rArray))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sourced allocation (Not really a cast, you are creating a temporary and copying it to the allocated array) is allowed by the standard (F2008 at least), but is not supported by the versions of gfortran I tried recently. For gfortran you currently must supply the boundaries of the allocated array even if you do not change the kind at all:

```
allocate(dArray(10), SOURCE=somearray)
```

Comment: is this any different from doing `allocate(dArray(10)) ; dArray=rArray ` ?

Comment: Basically no, but you avoid a potential temporary when splitting it. But `Ifort` does not give a temporary array warning in the original case either.